# Textfield only displays white box

Tags: actionscript-3, text, flashdevelop

Please help- despite lots of small changes- the result is always the same- no text.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import board;
    import flash.accessibility.AccessibilityImplementation;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.AntiAliasType; 
    import flash.utils.describeType;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Michael
     */

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {     
        [Embed(source = "C:/Windows/Fonts/Verdana.ttf", fontName = "Verdana", fontWeight = "bold", advancedAntiAliasing = "true", mimeType = "application/x-font")] 
        public static const VERD:Class;
            /*[Embed(source="../lib/StartText.txt",mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
             private var myFile:Class;
            public var b:ByteArray = new myFile();
            public var s:String = b.readUTFBytes(b.length)

        */


        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init():void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var board1:Sprite = new board();   
            stage.addChild(board1);



            var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();

            myTextBox.text = "Jabble. Click to Scroll Down . Instructions alternate between English and Japanese (translations). Press H for the help web page or put http://wp.me/P3FUQl-n in your web browser.  Beneath is the Board and to the right is the Box where further instruction display as ~-~ which means Press or use mouse to ~ to do ~. Click and Drag Tiles to move it and double click it set it on a square space on the Board or Box and click on the Box to change its mode. Jabble-" ;
            //(下にスクロールする]をクリック) 英語と日本語（訳）との間で交互に指示。を押して、ヘルプWebページのHまたはWebブラウザでhttp://wp.me/P3FUQl-nを置く。下には、取締役会であり、右に?などのさらなる命令ディスプレイボックスです - ?そのプレスを意味するか、やって?にマウスを使用して?。クリックして、それを移動するにはタイルをドラッグし、ダブル会またはボックス上の正方形のスペースには、それを設定してクリックし、そのモードを変更するには、ボックスをクリックしてください
            myTextBox.x=32;
            myTextBox.y=32;
            myTextBox.width = 32*13;  
            myTextBox.height = 32*13; 
            myTextBox.multiline = true; 
            myTextBox.wordWrap = true; 
            myTextBox.background = true; 
            myTextBox.border = true; 

            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat("VERD",20); 


            format.font = "Verdana"; 

            format.color = 0xFF0000; 
            format.size = 20; 

            myTextBox.defaultTextFormat = format; 
            myTextBox.embedFonts = true;
             myTextBox.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
            stage.addChild(myTextBox); 
            //myTextBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownScroll); 
                            //
            //function mouseDownScroll(event:MouseEvent):void 
        //{ 
            //myTextBox.scrollV++; 
        //}         
        //
            //
            //
            //stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown);
            //function myKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            //if (e.keyCode ==Keyboard.SPACE) 
            //{
            //removeChild(myTextBox);
            //myTextBox = null; 
            //
            }



} 

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add setTextFormat

```
 var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana",20); 

 format.color = 0xFF0000; 
 format.size = 20;  

 myTextBox.defaultTextFormat = format; 
 myTextBox.setTextFormat(format);
 myTextBox.embedFonts = true;
```

Comment: myTextBox.embedFonts = true;- trial and error shows the problem is this line- it also does not like opaquebackground and background being  set. So much for tutorials help- I was directed to include that embedFont line.

Answer (score 0):

try setting

```
myTextBox.textColor = 0xFF0000;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply- makes no difference.

Comment: I tried adding this and all it did was make top line and left line of the text field border blue.  myTextBox.opaqueBackground = 0x0000FF; //blue background